# How do I assign click handlers to each child with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menuitem-on" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="menuitem-off" id="mycart">My Cart</div>
    <div class="menuitem-off" id="shop">Shop</div>
</div>
```

how do I assign click handlers to each of the children of menu with jquery?

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#menu").delegate('div','click', function(){
//do your thing here
});
```

Handler is on parent, so only one.  You can add more div without changing code.

Here is a fiddle page to show a couple of different selector options to get the click anywhere, or just the first level.  Shows the use of the event target, currentTarget as well: http://jsfiddle.net/8GLZJ/

Update 3/18/2013 for 1.9.1+ jQuery use:

```
$("#menu").on('click','div', function(){
//do your thing here
});
```

Comment: BTW. You've made a mistake in params order - first and second should be replaced ;)

Comment: Thanks, made that change - so you type faster AND better!

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to do that because:

- You create a event handler for each children
- If you dynamically add more elements, the handler won't work for them.

A better solution is to add a single event handler to the parent element and then do a different action based on the `event.target` property, that contains the clicked element.

This happens because of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and it's a cool feature you should take advantage of.

jQuery in particular abstracts this under what they call [live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/) so you should go with those.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#menu div").click(function(){
   // your code goes here
   // $(this) give you the element that was clicked
});
```

Comment: this is correct but creates an event handler for each element, you should always try to append the handler to the parent element and discriminate by `event.target`

Comment: I agree with @Pablo (and I up voted his answer). That is the best way to do it. The above code will work however.

Answer (score 2):

Binding event to each one of element using `click()` or `bind('click', ...)` isn't a good solution, because in case if you have, lets say 50 items, you will have to bind 50 same handlers - browser has to register them all.

Better solution is to use feature called event delegation - and jQuery has special method for that - [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). So your code will look like this:

```
$('#menu').delegate('div', 'click', function() {
    //code of your handler - 'this' refers to clicked element
});
```

There is an article with video showing difference between `click`, `live` and `delegate` in jQuery: [NetTuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/).

Comment: you typed faster than I did :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$("#menu div").on('click', function(){
    //alert('clicked');
});
```